# Entity Framework not setting column, causing failure on INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have some code in EF that inserts into a table. I have a foreign key on CreatedBy column

C# Code

```
 var t = new ProductPackage();
 t.ProductSizeId = size.Id;
 t.IsActive = true;
 t.PackageSizeId = package.PackageSizeId;
 t.SAPId = package.SAPId;
 t.CarrierCode = package.CarrierCode;
 t.CaseUPCSupplierPack = package.CaseUPCSupplierPack; 
 t.CreatedBy = 1;
 t.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
 t.UpdatedBy = 1;
 t.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
 _dbContext.ProductPackages.Add(t);
 _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ProductPackages_ToCreated". The conflict occurred in database "pricing", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.

Here is the SQL Generating on the DB

```
INSERT [dbo].[ProductPackages]([ProductSizeId], [PackageSizeId], 
[CarrierCode], [SAPId], [CaseUPCSupplierPack], [CreatedBy], [CreatedDate], 
[UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate], [IsActive])
VALUES (@0, @1, NULL, NULL, @2, @3, NULL, @4, NULL, @5)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[ProductPackages]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()


-- @0: '631' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: '46' (Type = Int32)

-- @2: 'fsdfds' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 50)

-- @3: '0' (Type = Int32)

-- @4: '0' (Type = Int32)

-- @5: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
```

As you can see, I am supplying '1' as the CreatedBy field, and that Id exists in the User Table. What am I missing here?

**table script**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductPackages]

(

   [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY identity,

   [ProductSizeId] int not null,

   [PackageSizeId] int not null,

   [CarrierCode] varchar(50) NULL ,

   [SAPId] INT,

   [CaseUPCSupplierPack] VARCHAR(50),

   [CreatedBy]  int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 

[CreatedDate] DATETIME  DEFAULT getdate(), 

[UpdatedBy]  int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 

[UpdatedDate] DATETIME DEFAULT getdate(), 

[IsActive] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 

CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductPackages_ToProductSize] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductSizeId]) REFERENCES [ProductSizes]([Id]), 

CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductPackages_ToPackageSize] FOREIGN KEY ([PackageSizeId]) REFERENCES [PackageSizes]([Id]), 

   CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductPackages_ToCreated] FOREIGN KEY ([CreatedBy]) REFERENCES [Users]([Id]),

   CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductPackages_ToUpdated] FOREIGN KEY ([UpdatedBy]) REFERENCES [Users]([Id]),

)
```

Comment: Are you using Database-first or Code-first? What is the definition of your `ProductPackages` table in SQL and in EF (EDMX or Code)? Does EF believe the column has database-generated values?

Comment: @3 should be your "CreatedBy" id, and that contains '0'?

Comment: It is code first from existing database. So the dbcontext is generated from db

Comment: @steven but my code is populating it to 1.

Comment: True, but the SQL generated seems to reset this to zero (the default value for an int32), so there must be a reason for this. Can you show the table definition of the FK and the ProductPackage table?

Comment: Since the name of the FK constraint has ToCreated in it, maybe you have a field called ToCreated that is not nullable that is related to the users table, and is not being assigned a value in the above sql?

Comment: Added table scripts